# Does/ can Google's ARCore work on a Kindle?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, arcore, kindle

I'm currently developing a Unity3D app for a Kindle Fire using Google's ARCore, and I'm running through their Android quickstart guide. With how Amazon blocks any external or foreign links (i.e. anything but their own "Appstore"), running the app and allowing it to download its required APK version of ARCore is near impossible without interruption (app store can't be disabled/ force stopped).

There's a glimmer of it working as I download the APK (the hopefully correct version) through the device's browser and installing it (no prompt on launch to open app store etc.), but soon after, the same "ARCore encountered a problem connecting. Please start the app again" prompt appears as before. If it's truly a connection issue, I'd assume Amazon's intervening.

I'm asking if anyone has had better luck with Kindle, older models of Kindle, APK versions, and thereafter, versions of Unity and API levels where they've successfully installed ARCore related apps.

Unity ver. 2019.1.3f1

Kindle Fire HD 8

Fire OS 6.3.0.1

API level 25

ARCore Unity SDK v1.9.0

I tried both of the latest versions of the ARCore APK, uninstalling between the two;

ARCore 1.9.190422066

ARCore 1.9.190422069

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Google Arcore Supported Devices:  Google Pixel, Pixel XL , Samsung Galaxy S8 с Android 7.0

Comment: Thanks, there's also this table (https://developers.google.com/ar/discover/supported-devices) listing supported platforms. Could it be that ARCore is intentionally averting the Kindle platform, or there's a hardware requirement that's left undocumented?
It's unfortunate as I don't have the luxury of choice.